# Can't Install or FInd AMD Graphic Driver. (Ubuntu 17.10, Intel i3 6006u, AMD Radeon M330)

Tags: graphics, hybrid-graphics

I need solution. I can't even install drivers. I have tried using fglrx.15 and some extra. Tried to instal amd gpu pro but got trouble with the os. However I manage to get out of that and I can't even find intel hd graphics drivers

Comment: Im trying but Im unable to do that.Could you just tell me the procedure to do that for all applications.and I have tried the steps some of are with the error link "cant find executable" and for opengl amd thing it shows  virtual drives error

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.